# Is there any built-in method for the implementation of 'trees' in python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, binary-tree

Is there any built-in method for the implementation of **trees** in python 3.6?
If not, please explain the same with another method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of tree you're talking about. There is the binary tree library (it's really a learning library, but might be useful:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/binarytree/1.1.1

If your trees aren't binary, one option is to just use dictionaries of dictionaries:

```
import collections

def Tree():
    return collections.defaultdict(Tree)
```

Read more about this method here: https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250

There's also treelib: https://github.com/caesar0301/treelib

In other words, there are lots of possible implementations, but it depends on what you need. If you can add more detail to what you want to do, you will get better suggestions.

Comment: and for n-ary tree>?

Comment: Sorry, I guess my answer wasn't clear, only the first suggestion was for binary trees, the other two are more general. I've edited it to make that more clear.